# How to append a div to another div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
var contentofsel=$("#"+a).html().trim();
alert (contentofsel);

$('#temstoredivid').append(
  "<div class="maincover" id="maincov1">" + 
  "  <div class="subcover" id="subcover1"> </div>" +
  "  <div class="forclose" id="forcloseid1"> </div>" + 
  "</div>");

$('#temstoredivid .maincov1').html(contentofsel);
```

I need to print the value of contentofsel in div class subcover and id="subcover1" .I have tried the above code but not working. Please help me sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string literals are not properly enclosed

```
var contentofsel = $("#" + a).html().trim();
alert(contentofsel);

var $el = $('<div class="maincover" id="maincov1">' +
    '  <div class="subcover" id="subcover1 "></div>' +
    '  <div class="forclose" id="forcloseid1"></div>' +
    '</div>').appendTo('#temstoredivid');
//but since you are going to override the contents of .maincover element why are you adding 2 div's inside it in the above segment

$el.html(contentofsel);
```